# Call extension function from different class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to create a very simple transaction manager like this:

```
object PersistenceManager {
    private val dataSource: DataSource by lazy {
        val config = ConfigFactory.load()
        hikari(config.getConfig("postgres"))
    }

    private fun hikari(appConfig: Config): DataSource {
        // init datasource
    }

    fun <T> transaction(statement: Connection.() -> T): T {
        val connection = dataSource.connection
        try {
            return connection.statement()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            connection.rollback()
            throw e
        } finally {
            connection?.close()
        }
    }
}

class BrandsDB {

    private val query = "select name from brands order by name"

    fun Connection.getAll(): List<String> {
        val ps = this.prepareStatement(query)
        val rs = ps.executeQuery()
        return JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance()
            .newMapper(String::class.java)!!.stream(rs).toList()
    }
}

class BrandsService(private val brandsDB: BrandsDB) {

    fun getBrands(): List<String> {
        return transaction {
            brandsDB.getAll() // I'd like to do something like this but since
                              // getAll() method belongs to Connecion, I can't
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea behind all this is that I can have multiple queries in a single `transaction` block which I can rollback if anything goes wrong (should I have inserts or updates in those queries). I'd also like to avoid passing the connection to the `brandsDB.getAll()` method, but have it get the connection in an "implicit" way.

I know I could extract `getAll()` method to its own file or make `BrandsDB` class an object, but that'd make it possible to call the method anywhere in a static way, which I don't like. I'd also wouldn't like to put any DB related code in the `BrandsService`, only business logic should go there.

Would this be possible?

Comment: In your case it will be `return PersistenceManager.transaction { with(brandsDB) { getAll() } }`.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection` is an interface (not class!) in Java, so you may create your own interface that extends it and delegates to it.

```
interface OurConnection : Connection {
   fun getAll() : SomeType
}

fun <T> PersistenceManager.extendedTransaction(action: OurConnection.() -> T) : T {
   //call the original method
   return PersistenceManager.transaction {
      object : OurConnection, Connection by this {
         override fun getAll() = TODO("implement me")
      }.action()
   }
}
```

I use the delegated implementation, to implicitly delegate `Connection` methods in my interface. It is the `Connection by this` line, where `this` is the lambda receiver object from the `PersistenceManager.transaction` function call.

Comment: The solution provided by @Alexey Romanov actually solved my issue, thanks!